# SpriteKit Hero movement choke on nodes' connection

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

My game is a sidescroller, so the Hero has the constant speed, which is set to his velocity every update. When I form a floor with several "boxes", Hero stops where the first one ends and the second begins. They're of the same size and are on the same y-axis, why does this happen?

PhysicsBody of Hero:

```
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rect.size, center: center)
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Category.Hero
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Category.Floor | Category.Hero | Category.Glass | Category.Obstacle
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Category.Obstacle | Category.Glass | Category.Collision | Category.Doors | Category.EBullet | Category.Enemy | Category.Explosion | Category.Plyuha | Category.Slime
```

PhysicsBody for obstacle:

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size_sprite)
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Category.Obstacle
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Category.Bullet | Category.EBullet
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Category.Hero | Category.Bullet | Category.EBullet
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Do you have physics bodies associated with the hero and the boxes?

Comment: @claassenApps I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I would create a edge-based physics body that stretches the length of the screen to simulate the floor. This should keep the player from stopping at the edges of your floor pieces because it's a continues edge. you could then try putting any obstacles in front of the player.

Set the physics body like this:

```
let startPoint = CGPoint() // fill in the desired x and y for start point
let endPoint = CGPoint() // fill in the desired x and y for start point

self.floor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y), toPoint: CGPoint(x: endPoint.x, y: endPoint.y))
```

For other obstacles that might be stopping the player, try debugging by showing where the physics bodies actually are. There might be something you're not expecting to see blocking the player from advancing.

In the viewController, put

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

Comment: I use a similar solution for the floor, yes, but the problem occurs whenever there is a platform, on which floor is represented be more than one kind of block, for example, when there is a trap door, which cannot be covered by an edge, since it has to have opening functionality

Comment: I would try showing the physics bodies while the game is running to see if there's something unexpected blocking the player from advancing. See my updated answer. Be aware that there is a memory leak as long as you're viewing the physics bodies. It's on Apple's end and will hopefully be fixed soon. The memory leak will go away when you turn off the showPhysics property.

Comment: I've done that already and, clearly, nothing is on the Hero's way, so, I don't know, will have to figure out something else. However, thank you for your effort

Comment: Another thing you could try is removing the collisionBitMasks one at a time to see if one is causing the player to stop because of a collision.

Comment: that would result in Hero falling through the spriteNode